# converting my Java code to C properly ( error: no matching function for call to 'power1')

Tags: java, c

I wrote this recursive program in Java and I'm having problems converting it to C.(just started learning C)

My java code

```
public class Power
{
  static int count;

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    double[] base = { 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0 };
    int[]      index = { 5, 20, 63, 73, -1 };
    double   value;

    System.out.println( "\nTest two algorithms for powering\n" );
    for( int i=0 ; i<base.length ; i++ )
    {
      count = 0;
      value = power1( base[i], index[i] );
      System.out.println( "1: " + base[i] + "^" + index[i] + " = " + value + ", used " + count + " multiplies" );

      count = 0;
      value = power2( base[i], index[i] );
      System.out.println( "2: " + base[i] + "^" + index[i] + " = " + value + ", used " + count + " multiplies" );
      System.out.println();
    }


  }

  public static double power1( double base, int index )
  {
    double retValue;

    assert( index>=0 );

    if( index == 0 )
    {
      retValue = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      retValue = base * power1( base, index-1 );
      count++; 
    }

    return retValue;
  }

  public static double power2( double base, int index )
  {
    double retValue;
    double temp;

    assert( index>=0 );

    if( index == 0 )
    { 
      retValue = 1;
    }
    else if( index%2 == 1 )
    {
      retValue = base * power2( base, index-1 );
      count++;
    }
    else
    {
      temp = power2( base, index/2 );
      retValue = temp*temp;
      count++;
    }

    return retValue;
  }
}
```

the C code I'm working on...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

//#define count;
#define ARRAY_LENGTH 5

static int count;

double power1(double base, int index);
double power2(double base, int index);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    double base[5] = {1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0};
    int index[5] = {5, 20, 63, 73, -1};
    double value;

    printf("%s\n", "test two algorithms for powering\n" );
    for(double i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++){
        count = 0;
        //value = power1(base[i], index[i]);
        value = power1(base, index);

        printf("1: %f^%d = %f, used %d multiples", base,index,value,count);

        count =0;

        value = power2(base, index);

        printf("2: %f^%d = %f, used %d multiples", base[i],index[i],value,count);

    }




}

double power1(double base[5], int index[5]){
    double retValue;
    double temp;

    assert(index>=0);

    if(index ==0){
        retValue=1;
    }else if(index%2 ==1){
        retValue = base * power2(base, index-1);
        count++;
    }else{
        temp = power2(base, index/2);
        retValue = temp * temp;
        count++;
    }

    return retValue;
}


double power2(double base[5], int index[5]){
    double retValue;
    double temp;

    assert(index >=0);

    if(index ==0){
        retValue=1;

    }else if( index %2 ==1){
        retValue = base * power2(base, index-1);
        count++;
    }else{
        temp = power2(base, index/2);
        retValue = temp * temp;
        count++;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

These are my errors and warnings(most of them are repeated):

```
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:22:11: error: no matching function for call to 'power1'
                value = power1(base, index);
                        ^~~~~~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:10:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double [5]' to 'double' for 1st argument
double power1(double base, int index);
       ^
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:25:46: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
                printf("1: %f^%d = %f, used %d multiples", base,index,value,count);
                           ~~                              ^~~~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:25:51: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
                printf("1: %f^%d = %f, used %d multiples", base,index,value,count);
                              ~~                                ^~~~~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:29:11: error: no matching function for call to 'power2'
                value = power2(base, index);
                        ^~~~~~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:11:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double [5]' to 'double' for 1st argument
double power2(double base, int index);
       ^
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:32:50: error: array subscript is not an integer
                printf("2: %f^%d = %f, used %d multiples", base[i],index[i],value,count);
                                                               ^~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:32:59: error: array subscript is not an integer
                printf("2: %f^%d = %f, used %d multiples", base[i],index[i],value,count);
                                                                        ^~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:49:16: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int')
        }else if(index%2 ==1){
                 ~~~~~^~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:50:21: error: no matching function for call to 'power2'
                retValue = base * power2(base, index-1);
                                  ^~~~~~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:11:8: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double *' to 'double' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
double power2(double base, int index);
       ^
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:53:28: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int')
                temp = power2(base, index/2);
                                    ~~~~~^~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:71:18: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int')
        }else if( index %2 ==1){
                  ~~~~~ ^~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:72:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double *' and 'double')
                retValue = base * power2(base, index-1);
                           ~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/elle/Desktop/power.c:75:28: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int')
                temp = power2(base, index/2);
                                    ~~~~~^~
2 warnings and 10 errors generated.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

The output is supposed to be like

```
Test two algorithms for powering

1: 1.4^5 = 5.378239999999998, used 5 multiplies
2: 1.4^5 = 5.378239999999998, used 4 multiplies

1: 1.3^20 = 190.04963774880824, used 20 multiplies
2: 1.3^20 = 190.04963774880818, used 6 multiplies

1: 1.2^63 = 97368.50480227199, used 63 multiplies
2: 1.2^63 = 97368.50480227212, used 11 multiplies

1: 1.1^73 = 1051.1531995000591, used 73 multiplies
2: 1.1^73 = 1051.1531995000587, used 9 multiplies

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at Power.power1(Power.java:31)
    at Power.main(Power.java:15)
```

I'm mixing up java with c in most ways, I've been searching for how to fix these errors now for hours.

> Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mean to be passing arrays to your functions:

```
double power1(double base[5], int index[5])
```

does not match the Java version:

```
public static double power1( double base, int index )
```

and should be simply:

```
double power1(double base, int index)
```

The same with `power2`.

Somehow, you got the declarations right but the definitions wrong.

You also need to do `value = power1( base[i], index[i] );` just like in the Java version.

Comment: I corrected those already but I am still getting this error `error: no matching function for call to 'power1'`on this line of code `value = power1(base[i], index[i]);`, I can't seem to figure out why